# PHP Imagick() is taking to long to excecute

Tags: php, imagick

I running this script to create a jpg image from a pdf.

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(300, 300);
$im->readImage($temp_path . $file);
if ($im->getImageColorspace() == \Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK) {
    $profiles = $im->getImageProfiles('*', false);
    // we're only interested if ICC profile(s) exist 
    $has_icc_profile = (array_search('icc', $profiles) !== false);
    // if it doesnt have a CMYK ICC profile, we add one 
    if ($has_icc_profile === false) {
        $icc_cmyk = file_get_contents(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/USWebUncoated.icc');
        $im->profileImage('icc', $icc_cmyk);
        unset($icc_cmyk);
    }
    // then we add an RGB profile 
    $icc_rgb = file_get_contents(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc');
    $im->profileImage('icc', $icc_rgb);
    unset($icc_rgb);
 }
 $im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
 $im = $im->flattenImages();
 $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
 $im->thumbnailImage(900, 900, true);
```

Is working fine but the problem is that is taking to long to excecute. and some time if the file have to much detail I get a timeout excecution from php.

I was using it before without the profileImage() file and was working perfect, but the color on the CMYK was not right.

How can I make better and efficient. I running this on linux with php5.5.9

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [cloudinary.com](http://cloudinary.com), check it out, it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is any faster and still contains the correct color:

```
<php
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage($temp_path . $file); //pdf
if ($im->getImageColorspace() == \Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK) {
  $im->transformImageColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
}
$im->writeImage('out.jpg'); // jpg
?>
```

Comment: I try that before and did't work. that is way I load the profile colors